# Proof of propositional logic theorem using Induction on Formulas

Tags: induction, propositional-calculus

How to prove the following theorem using induction on formulas?

> Let V and V' be two valuations of L. Let $\alpha$ be a formula such that V(p) = V'(p), for all atomic formula p that is subformula of $\alpha$. Then V($\alpha$) = V'($\alpha$).

The base case is simple: If $\alpha$ is an atomic formula, then it does not have a subformula so V($\alpha$) = V'($\alpha$). But how to proceed using induction on formulas?

Comment: Not correct your statement; If $α$  is an atomic formula, then it **is** a single atomic subformula: call it $p$. Then from $V(p) = V'(p)$, for all atomic formula p that is subformula of $α$, we conclude with: $V(α) = V'(α)$.

Comment: Induction step: consider at least two connectives: $\lnot, \lor$. For $\lnot$: if $\alpha = \lnot \beta$ for some $\beta$, and consider $V(p) = V'(p)$, for all atomic formula $p$ that is subformula of $α$. Obviously, the $p$'s are also subformulae of $\beta$ and thus we apply the induction hypotheses : $V(\beta) = V'(\beta)$. Then ...

Comment: Thank you! I am trying the case where $\alpha = \beta \lor \gamma$. Should i use $V(\beta) = V'(\beta)$ and $V(\gamma) = V'(\gamma)$ separated and then use $\lor$ connective?